# How to create custom Error in Nodejs with Status Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Error Handler Function

```
const MyCustomError =(code,sms)=>{
    let err = new Error(sms)
    err.code =code
    return err
}

  module.exports ={MyCustomError}
```

required response[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTLbv.jpg)
but it gives server Error with sms

```
res.status(400).send({ status: false, message: `This ==> ${data.number} mobile number belongs to another user` })
```

Comment: “It gives server error” isn’t terribly helpful. Please provide complete details: what’s supposed to happen, what does happen, and the circumstances under which it happens/doesn’t happen.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: throw returns custom error but not desired custom response like res.status(400).send.I want to return response with status code using throw instead of  res.status(400).send but postman gives server error with response???